Why is LibreOffice Calc doubling the number of pages when printing?
I'm using LibreOffice 7.4.7.2 on Debian 12.
I have a sheet with 363 rows and 4 columns. There are no "phantom" rows or columns, so when I press Ctrl+End in the keyboard, I go to the 363rd row, 4th column (all filled with data).
When I see a print preview, the 4th column's right border keeps a visible distance from the page right margin (all the four columns are inside the margins).
So I see no reason for the addition of empty pages at all. However, my document data fills 8 pages (A4 size), but there are other 8 empty pages at the end. Why is that? And how do I remove them?
I have read about empty pages being added to make the total number even, but that's not the case here.

Though you checked that last column did not overlap, likely it did, dependent on paper size, etc. Try shrinking column widths more.

@DrMoishePippik Indeed! The Print Preview margins display is not as precise as it should. Thank you!
